# iOS- ScrollView not working with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, scrollview, constraints, xcode6.1

I am trying to add scroll view with AutoLayout. But ScrollView not working.
Here I attached screen shot.[image]

Comment: Thank you my folks :), I solved this issue with this line self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.contentView.bounds.size.width, 530);I added this in -(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.window.frame.size.width, 530);
```

Set your scrollView ContentSize .

Comment: Thank you, With this line I can scroll horizontally and vertically also. How can I disable horizontally scrolling?

Comment: just set the width and height .. Width for Horizontal and Height for Vertical .

Answer (score 0):

Pin your scroll view's leading, trailing, top and bottom space to the superview in your storyboard
[image: Pin view to superview's bounds]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting scrollView `contentSize` in `-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews` method. This method invokes after autolayout is done.

Comment: -(void)viewDidAutolayoutSubview method not available, I think you are pointing to -(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews. Is this correct?